# Practicing Interview Question, Find Largest sum Of Two Consecutive Numbers In An Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I found an interview practice question as stated in the title. Everything so far seems correct, however my `if` and `else-if` statements for comparing stored values of each sum are letting me down. If the largest sum is obtained from the FIRST TWO elements of the array, then it does not work. If they are anywhere else, then it does.

I thought I logically get why this is the case hence why I have an `else-if` statement which I thought would fix it. The answer found is 51, but this is incorrect. It should be the FIRST TWO (100+50). I feel like my logic is failing me and any guidance would be great!

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main { //Qn is to find the largest sum of two consecutive numbers in an array

    public Main() {}

    private static int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] intArray = new int[]{100, 50, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0};
        ArrayList<Integer> sumArray = new ArrayList<>();
        int sum;
        int answer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < (intArray.length - 1); i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < intArray.length; j++) {
                sum = intArray[i] + intArray[j];
                sumArray.add(sum);

            }
        }

        for (int temp = 0; temp < (sumArray.size()-1); temp++) {
            for (int temp1 = 1; temp1 < sumArray.size(); temp1++) {
                if(sumArray.get(temp) > sumArray.get(temp1)){
                    answer = sumArray.get(temp);
                }
                else if (sumArray.get(temp) < sumArray.get(temp1)) {
                    answer = sumArray.get(temp1);
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Actual answer = 51. Expected answer = 150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a lot of code, and I'm not certain why you are comparing `sumArray.get(temp)` with `sumArray.get(temp1)` - you should compare with **`answer`**; but honestly, we can simplify this.

Start by initializing `answer` to the smallest possible value. Then iterate the array once and compare ***consecutive*** sums with the current `answer`. Like,

```
int[] intArray = { 100, 50, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0 };
int answer = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length - 1; i++) {
    int sum = intArray[i] + intArray[i + 1];
    answer = Math.max(answer, sum);
}
System.out.println(answer);
```

If using Java 8+, you could simplify it further by using a lambda to map the array values and stream that into `max()`. Like,

```
int[] intArray = { 100, 50, 0, 50, 1, 0, 0 };
int answer = IntStream.range(0, intArray.length - 1)
        .map(i -> intArray[i] + intArray[i + 1])
        .max()
        .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: We're lowkey on the same wave length. I like that usage of Integer.MIN_VALUE, quite nice. To the top!

Comment: @Jason There are only so many reasonable ways to implement the given requirements.

Comment: This is true ^^, could have maybe thrown IllegalArgumentException indicating < 2 length.

Comment: Okay, I have heard of lambda expressions but haven't got to it so this .max and .orElse is quite confusing to me. I do not expect you to take more time out of your day to explain this too, if so, do you have any good sources where I can understand this method of writing code better, it seems short and sweet and I'd love to know more!

Comment: @BradleyBrown [Lambda Expressions: The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Perfect, I'll take a look! How useful are they (aside from this), are they commonly used?

Comment: @BradleyBrown They weren't added to the language until Java 8, but lambdas are very useful and are more commonly used every day.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create an IntStream with a range of 0 to the array length - 1 and then map the sum of values[index] and values[index + 1] and then find the max, otherwise return -1.

```java
    private static int max(int[] values) {
        return IntStream.range(0, values.length - 1)
                .map(index -> values[index] + values[index + 1])
                .max()
                .orElse(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh I over-complicated it. I've never seen the  continue statement, can you explain because I feel like that is making sure that the "otherIndex" is one ahead, is this true? If so, how does it work?

Comment: My initial implementation took into non-consecutive values as I didn't properly read the question. Refer to @Elliot Frisch's response below. All we're simply doing with this resolution is looping through the entire array, except the last index since it's already taken into consideration in the second last index.